# Grammatical correctness of a sentence

Tags: grammatical-number

Recently I read a sentence -

> The French Rooms, at least until modern periods are reached, are a demonstration that in the sphere of aesthetics, science does not produce the greatest artists - that something other than intelligent interest and technical accomplishment *are* requisite to that end, and that system is fatal to spontaneity.

I am not sure if *'are'* instead of *'is'* should be used since it is referring to *'that something other'* which seems to be clearly singular. So what should it be?

Comment: Yes, it should be *is*.

Such grammatical slips are an occupational hazard of the writer who produces complex, unwieldy sentences like the one you quoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right. It is singular, and so the verb should be *is*. The writer was clearly, and wrongly, influenced to choose *are* by the proximity of the coordinated *intelligent interest and technical accomplishment*.

That apart, the sentence is not well constructed. The reader is distracted from the start by the strange use of capital letters in *french Room*.

Comment: oh the french rooms is a typo..I'll correct it.

Answer (score 1):

The "French Rooms" could be referring to a specific set of rooms in a specific house, in which case capitalization is OK.  But the sentence is still pretty clumsy.

"...  something other than intelligent interest and technical accomplishment is requisite to" clear writing.